# Slider functionality for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, slider

I am having a plain html table which I need to apply sorting and sliding feature using jQuery. I have applied the sorting through by using DataTable.js jQuery library. Sorting is working fine but don't know how to apply slider to the table like as shown below making all the subjects columns within a slider and student name and total columns as fixed

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

My code is as given below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4sbh73uz/)**

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    myTable= $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "bInfo": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student</th>
            <th>Maths</th>
            <th>Physics</th>
            <th>Geography</th>
            <th>History</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Computer</th>
            <th>Biology</th>
            <th>Chemistry</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jeffrey</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>67</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>445</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mathew</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>76</td>
            <td>78</td>
            <td>98</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>545</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Linson</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>98</td>
            <td>97</td>
            <td>86</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>454</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Filson</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>76</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>78</td>
            <td>98</td>
            <td>545</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Felix</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>89</td>
            <td>97</td>
            <td>96</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>86</td>
            <td>565</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Akhil</td>
            <td>78</td>
            <td>98</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>67</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>676</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arjun</td>
            <td>67</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>788</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arun</td>
            <td>57</td>
            <td>87</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>99</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>898</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed header plugin could help you regarding this. You can see the fixed header in [example here](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/).

`updated`[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4mte67mc/)

Comment: can you give me a jsfiddle

Comment: but somehow when we slide towards right we can see it is going behind the student name column

Comment: Yes, you may need to play around with this a bit, I am sure you will succeed as in example there and freeze last column as well since its feature says that you can freeze 2 or more columns

Comment: as you said I have succeded but how can I restrict scroll bar only to the scrollable columns, now the scrollbar is applied to the entire table including the fixed columns http://jsfiddle.net/4mte67mc/1/

Comment: Glad to know that you worked it out, I don't know if they had something to limit scrolling to particular columns and it may look little odd too.

Comment: is there any other plugin which is available to make up a view like as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

Add scrollX to your dataTable

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').dataTable( {
         "scrollX": true
       } );
     } );
```

Comment: but its a scroller and also we cant fix the student and total column fixed